# PHP form stay on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi i am trying to update data in a database from a form on the same page as the php code without redirecting/reloading the page.

I tried this tutorial but that didn't work: [http://www.formget.com/form-submit-without-page-refreshing-jquery-php](http://www.formget.com/form-submit-without-page-refreshing-jquery-php/)/

Update code:

```
<?php
include "db.php";
session_start();
$value=$_POST['name'];
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE users SET profiel='$value' WHERE username='$_SESSION['user']'");
?>
```

Profilecomplete.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (name == '') {
            alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
        } else {
        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            $.post("config/profilecomplete.php", {
                value: name
            }, function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The form:

```
<form method="POST" id="form">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="name">Value</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn-flat">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have a example/tutorial for this?

Comment: Could you edit your question with more of the code you are using? I haven't read the tutorial, but I assume there is some form of jQuery ajax being used, and I'm sure I'm not alone in wanting to follow the whole tutorial to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. Further question, do you receive any errors in the console or perhaps PHP errors on the page?

Comment: No first thing i checked before posting ;)

Comment: What you're looking for is an `SPA` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application Or at least components of it.

Comment: I can see you are still learning PHP. So a small tip: Never, ever, ever let userinput fill your query without escaping it. It's dagerous without (SQL injections).  Escape doing this: `$value= mysqli_real_escape_string ($connection, $_POST['name']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, it's working already.

**index.php**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var nameInput = $("#name").val();
        var name = {
            'name' : nameInput
        }
        if (nameInput == '') {
            alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
        } else {
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            $.post("config/profilecomplete.php", {value: name}, function(data) {
                alert(data);
                //$('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**profilecomplete.php**

```
<?php

$_POST = array_shift($_POST); // array_shift is very important, it lets you use the posted data.

echo $_POST['name'];


?>
```

if you want a more simple way.

try to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: How you will get $_POST['name'] from this?

Comment: `'name' : nameInput // this name here`

Comment: This works but it gives a popup with a error in it. Anyway to fix this? http://i.imgur.com/PFPpLTz.png line 27: `$value=$_POST['name'];`

Comment: or like this `'name' : $("#name").val(), 'pass': $("#pass").val()` careful with the comma separator. The term for that is `key value pairs`. and that is an object.

Comment: Other problem i am having is that if i for example post 2 different things they both post the data from input 1

Comment: @yul757 Too long for a comment: http://pastebin.com/S62i67eU `nameTwo` gives the same value as `name`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106019/discussion-between-yul757-and-amando-vledder).

Answer (score 0):

How your click event can occur even if you are not preventing the default behavior of the form submit button. Make the submit input as a button or use `event.preventDefault()` to submit the form via ajax.

```
<?php
include "db.php";
session_start();

if(isset($_POST)) {
    $value=$_POST['name'];
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE users SET profiel='$value' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['user']}'");
    echo ($query) ? "Updated" : "Not Updated";
    exit;
} else {
?>
<form method="POST" id="form">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="validate" name="name">
        <label for="name">Value</label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn-flat">Update</button>
</form>
<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (name === '') {
            alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
        } else {
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            $.post("config/profilecomplete.php", {name: name}, function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This gives me `Notice: Undefined index: name in` and only shows `Updated`

Comment: Updated my answer. Change {value: name} as {name:name}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue, or at least, one of the issues, is on this line;

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE users SET profiel='$value' WHERE username='$_SESSION['user']'");
```

You are opening and closing the single quotes twice, here

```
WHERE username='$_SESSION['user']'
```

Try using this instead;

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE users SET profiel='$value' WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["user"] . "'");
```